# Удаление комментариев

Tags: java

Добрый день!
В строке то что находится в {....} называется комментарием. Как удалить из строки все комментарии? Желательно с объяснением. Я могу лишь 1 комментарий удалить :(

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String s = "bla bla {za4em nado } bla bla { za4em nado} bla";
    int p = s.indexOf("{");
    int t = s.indexOf("}");
    String res;
    if (p == -1)  {
        res = s;
    } else {
        res = s.substring(0, p)+ s.substring(t+1);
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

Comment: А вложенные комментарии допускаются ? Судя по виду { ... } очень может быть.

Comment: вроде как допускаются.

Comment: Комментарий к @RainRaus.

К сожалению лимит комментариев к ответу у меня закончился (все таки это ограничение - **дурь**).

Да Вы герой. При таких бедах еще и о регэкспах в Java думать ! Не, я без иронии.

--

С WiFi я думаю, ноги растут из того же места, что и в проблеме с таблицей разделов. Винда не любит делиться, считает что это ее и только ее железо, а в природе больше никого нет.

Судиться с M$, IMHO, бессмысленно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("\\{.*?\\}"); // регулярное выражение поиска комментариев
Matcher match=pat.matcher(s); // получаем объект соответствий к строке s
String result=match.replaceAll(""); // заменяем все соответствия пустой строкой
```

Comment: так?  

public static void main(String[] args) { 
 String s = "bla bla {za4em nado } bla bla { za4em nado} bla";
 Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("\\{.*?}");
 Matcher match=pat.matcher(s);
 String res=match.replaceAll(" ");
     System.out.println(res);}}

Comment: Маленькое уточнение. Если в строке "x{abc}def}x" комментарием считается "abc}def", то предложенное @ReinRaus регулярное выражение сработает корректно. Если же в этой строке комментарием считается "abc", то регулярное выражение должно быть таким: "{[^}]*}".

Upd: Ещё одно. Класс String тоже имеет метод replaceAll(String, String). Таким образом код можно сократить до такого: 
String s = "{}{}{}";
s.replaceAll("{.*?}", "");

Comment: @Andrey2517, так все-таки, что с вложенностью, 

а главное распознаванием **некорректной** вложенности ?

Comment: String s = "bla bla {za4em nado } bla bla { za4em nado} bla";
     String s0;
     s0=s.replaceAll("\\{.*?}", " ");
     System.out.println(s0);

Comment: String s = "bla bla {za4em {nado} xaxa } bla bla { za4em nado} bla";

результат:

bla bla   xaxa } bla bla   bla

@Andrey2517, это правильно ?

Comment: ого, это косяк. спасибо)

Comment: @Andrey2517, IMHO регэкспами такая задача не решается.

Надо посимвольно обрабатывать строку, копируя символы в результат и вести "счетчик вложенности комментария". Если он больше нуля, то симолы в результат не копируются.

Comment: это печально.

Comment: А разве в java не работают нежадные квантификаторы? Я не тестировал приведенный мной пример.

Comment: Работают. Артем не прав.
Другое дело, что паттерн "{.*?}" не скомпилируется, т.к. {} обозначают числовой квантификатор и их нужно экранировать.

Comment: Дело тут не в нежадных квантификаторах, а в невозможности разобрать подобным регэкспом **вложенный комментарий**. 

Нежадный же съест все от начала первого комментария до конца последнего. Вы не можете написать регэксп, учитывающий **баланс** скобок.

@RainRaus, если советуете что-то, то за слова надо отвечать. По крайней мере **код проверять, чтобы хоть транслировался**.

Comment: @avp к сожалению на момент ответа у меня была голая Windows без единого ЯП, ввиду ужасных бед свалившихся на меня:  
[беда 1][1]  
[беда 2][2]  

[1]:http://user.hashcode.ru/questions/2600/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BA-microsoft
[2]:http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=188305.0

Comment: Примерно так можно сделать RegExp с учетом баланса скобок, правда в цикле и в выражении `1{2{3}` будет стерто `{3}`  

    Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("\\{[^{}]*\\}");
    String s="12{3{4}5}6789";
    String result=s;
    do {
        s=result;
        Matcher match=pat.matcher(s); 
        result=match.replaceAll("");
        System.out.println(result);
    } while (!s.equals(result));